# How to open a local file with Chrome using adb shell?

Tags: android, adb

I want to open a local file with Chrome from the adb shell. Something like

```
adb shell 'echo This is a test input file > input.txt'
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d input.txt
```

But it opens Chrome with the file name in the url but with an error message that the page cannot be opened. How can I do it?

Comment: Local files require to use the `file://` protocol and an absolute path. However on recent versions of Android there are several restrictions. See e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220400/2241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to open a file from /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.chrome/files/Download/ via chrome.